# What do you call those posters eye doctors use to test your eyesight?

Tags: phrase-request, image-identification

What do you call those posters eye doctors use to test your eyesight?

[image]

Comment: You should keep inflamatory politics out of questions about English - surely this is not the only example you could find of such a chart. The "humour" is not appreciated here. (I've submitted an edit with a more neutral example, without affecting the nature of your question)

Comment: @Grismar I couldn't google it since I didn't know what it's called, but I saw this meme

Comment: @Grismar by the way, your picture is of a different chart (with a different name) so strictly speaking you charged the question

Comment: I put "posters eye doctors use to test your eyesight" into google and found it. Please try harder

Answer (score 3):

These are called 'Snellen charts', or more generally an 'eye chart'.